# Is there existing a php project/class that gathering common social network api together?

Tags: php, facebook, social-networking

I am currently running a online community and want to expend its feature that people can have there SNS status updated on specific actions. I have experience with using APIs of Facebook, Twitter and Weibo a year ago, but I am tired keep updating them and the code are not quite consistent.

I would like to have a even higher level port that have APIs with common SNSs to handle user authentication, re-authorize permission, connection toggle, etc. for me. I know that SO is not quite a place for research but I failed to figure it out on google and I suppose this is quite a valuable resource for many people. Excuse me, but could anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HybridAuth enable developers to easily build social applications to engage websites vistors and customers on a social level by implementing social signin, social sharing, users profiles, friends list, activities stream, status updates and more.
>
> HybridAuth goal is to act as an abstract api between your application and various social apis and identities providers such as Facebook, Twitter, MySpace and Google.

I found that this works better.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/hybridauth/

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Temboo](http://www.temboo.com).

Temboo normalizes access to 100+ APIs (including many social network APIs), so that you can use a uniform syntax to interact with all of them. Temboo makes this functionality available through an SDK, which is available in many languages, including PHP.

Check out the [examples](https://www.temboo.com/examples) page for an overview of the sort of API-based behavior that Temboo makes easy.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: oh...that disclosure probably drives me some down-votes @@... Thank you anyway.

Comment: sorry but the apis are often covering very limited functions of the apis in my opinion

Comment: The down votes are due to the nature of your question. People prefer if you ask much more specific, code-oriented questions that ideally can be answered objectively.  

As regards Temboo, thanks for the feedback! We're always working to improve our Library so it would be great to hear about what you'd like in the Library. I'd really appreciate it if you mailed me your feedback - cormac.driver@temboo.com